# How to Return struct in a class when gthe struct is declared outside the class?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, getter-setter

I am trying to get the structure of strings "Johna" "Smith" to return by calling a class. I am very new and confused on OOP and pointers and I wanted to know if Im on the right track and what I can do to get rid of the following errors:

1. "cannot convert ‘name’ to ‘const char*’" on line 46... This line

```
printf(s1.get_name())
```

Any help is appreciated, here is the full code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <algorithm>  // for std::find
#include <cctype>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // for std::begin, std::end
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum year { FRESHMAN, SOPHOMORE, JUNIOR, SENIOR };
struct name {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
};
class Student : name {
   private:
    name Name;

   public:
    void setname(string fn, string ln) {
        Name.firstName = fn;
        Name.lastName = ln;
    }
    name get_name() { return Name; }
};

int main() {
    Student s1;
    s1.setname("johna", "smith");
    printf(s1.get_name()) return 0;
}
```

Comment: What were you hoping `printf(s1.get_name())` would do?

Comment: @Drew Dormann I hoped printf(s1.get_name()) would print "Johna" "Smith"

Comment: Prefer to avoid `printf` in C++ code. Better to use `ostreams` to have formatted output

Comment: @DandyApe -- Do not use other computer languages as a model in writing C++ code.  C++ is properly learned by reading good C++ books, not by guessing or using other languages to come up with a "good guess".

Comment: To clarify earlier comments - both `<stdio.h>` and `printf` are components of a different programming language, named C.  If you are very new to C++, the learning process will be much simpler if you don't try mixing it with other languages just yet.

Comment: side note: don't inherit `Student` from `name`. A student `has a` name, as possibly `has a` list of grades, but your Student  both `has a` and `is a` name. Just remove the inheritance, and keep the Name member variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is totally fine, you're just confused about the `printf` function of C++.

Maybe you have experience with python, javascript, or other scripting languages that the print function accepts anything and prints it out nicely. That is not the case with a strong typed language like C++.

You should read the [docs on printf](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

```cpp
name s1_name = s1.get_name();
printf("%s %s\n", s1_name.firstName.c_str(), s1_name.lastName.c_str());
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::cout`, which will handle the format type for you.

```cpp
std::cout << s1_name.firstName << ' ' << s1_name.lastName  << '\n';
```

You could also define a way to let `std::cout` know how to handle your struct:

```cpp
struct name
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const name& input)
    {
        os << input.firstName << ' ' << input.lastName << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};
...
std::cout << s1_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to what thedemons posted, when you do not provide format specifiers as the first argument to printf, it opens room for a potential format string vulnerability. Because you did not specify what format the first parameter is, if the user of the program was able to change the contents of Name to %x %x %x %x, the user would be able to read memory off of the stack and leak information which can lead to a plethora of issues. Make sure to always use format specifiers such as %s or %d to avoid these issues when using printf :)

Comment: Also, because you are using C++, it does not make much sense to use printf() as it is inherently an insecure function. Better to use std::cout

Comment: When I use cout<< s1.get_name()<<endl; i get the following errors: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘name’), no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>’

Comment: @DandyApe -- You get errors because `std::cout` has no idea how to print a `Name`, since there is no `operator <<` overload for `Name`.  As my comment in the main thread suggests, do not use Python or any other language to figure out things in C++.  Those languages have some sort of built-in "pretty printer" when given a class.  There is no such thing in C++ -- you have to write the code to tell `operator <<` what to do when it encounters a `Name` object.

Comment: @DandyApe `std::cout <<` is an operator that only accepts a variety of types that it knows how to format, like `std::string`, `int`, `float`, `char*`,... and so on. It doesn't know how to handle your struct `name`.

Comment: you have to overload the << operator in your Student class in order to use std::cout<< to print a name object because it does not understand how to parse that object into printable data unless you specify how to do so

Comment: @DandyApe if you want to use `std::cout << s1.get_name()`, please see the edit in my answer.

Comment: If your answer post doesn't answer the question standing alone and is intended only to add to / improve another answer, then you should suggest an edit to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

better is to use cout in c++

```
printf(s1.get_name())
```

should be

```
cout << s1.get_name();
```